# Speeding up full screen image drawing on iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, ffmpeg

I am developing an app which plays interactive real time streaming video.  I use FFMPEG (don't worry, I'll be releasing my source code) to decode a MPEG2/H264 RTP stream.  I simply cannot get the iPhone 3G to draw a screen full of pixels faster than 5 times per second.

I've tried a OpenGL texture which was just a slow.  I've also tried an array of 2D vertexes covering the entire screen and using glDrawArrays but that yielded 5 FPS as well.  For now I've stuck to simply drawing a CGImage onto my view which gives me about 7-8 FPS.

From what I gathered, the private CoreSurface framework seems to be the only way.  Anyone have any tips or tricks to get at least 20-30 FPS?  I'd hate to restrict my app to only the 3GS and iPod touches.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: While nobble, sometimes people just have to upgrade. If you create a killer app for 3GS, you create market forces which lure more people into upgrading, which makes this a non-issue.

Comment: How are you uploading your textures to GL ES?

Comment: @genpfault My frame is 480x320 so I add padding to the right and bottom to make it 512x512 and then pass the pointer to glTexImage2D.  I've also tried with glTexSubImage2D with the same results.

Comment: Andrew: Run Instruments with the Time Profiler instrument and see where your app is bogging down.

Comment: Releasing the source is only part of the story - H.264 is covered by patents, which is a totally separate issue to the license of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play H.264 and MPEG2 video on the iPhone, why are you doing the decoding yourself?  What do you need that MPMoviePlayer doesn't cover?

Comment: The only reason I do not use the MPMoviePlayerController is because I need to display the video in realtime.  Even with HTTP Live Streaming, the video is delayed too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are decoding in software, you're never going to get a good frame rate. Even on faster hardware (iPhone 3GS and 2nd/3rd gen iPod touches), you're going to drain the battery very quickly.